# What does this notation mean$ p_1 \ldots \frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y+1}{-1}=\frac{z-4}{1}, \quad p_2 \ldots \frac{x-5}{2}=\frac{y-1}{-1}=\frac{z-2}{1} . $

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an exercise with text: With lines

$$
p_1 \ldots \frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y+1}{-1}=\frac{z-4}{1}, \quad p_2 \ldots \frac{x-5}{2}=\frac{y-1}{-1}=\frac{z-2}{1} .
$$
Determine one plane $\pi$ with respect to which the lines $p_1$ and $p_2$ are symmetric.

How to approach this? I should somehow conclude that lines go through dots A1(1,-1,4) A2(5,1,2).

Comment: Convert the equations of your straight lines into parametric form $M=A_1+\mu \vec{v}, N=A_2+\lambda \vec{v}$. Your plane will be determined as the plane passing through $\frac12(A_1+A_2)$ and having a certain vector basis, one of the vectors of this basis being $\vec{v}$... it remaine to find another one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should first notice that $p_1$ and $p_2$ have the same direction. Because by construction, their direction vector is indeed $\vec u\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}$. So they are either parallel or are the very same line.

We know that they pass respectively by $A_1\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\4\end{pmatrix}$ and $A2\begin{pmatrix}5\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}$. Let us just test whether $A_2$ is member of $p_1$:

$$\frac{5 - 1}{2} = 2\\
\frac {1 + 1}{-1} = -2
$$

No it is not. We have $p_1 \parallel p_2$.

As $p_1$ and $p_2$ are expected to be symetric with respect to $\pi$, we know that $\pi$ contains the point $\frac{A_1 + A_2} 2 \begin{pmatrix}3\\0\\3\end{pmatrix}$ and that the vector $\vec u$ is one vector of $\pi$. To find another vector in order to fully define $\pi$, we can use $\vec w = \vec u \wedge \overrightarrow{A_1 A_2}$, which yields $\vec w\begin{pmatrix}-3\\-3\\3\end{pmatrix}$, or even better $\vec v = \frac{-\vec w} 3$: $\vec v\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$ (as $\vec w$ is orthogonal to both $\vec u$ and $\overrightarrow{A_1 A_2}$ it must be a vector of $\pi$).

So $\pi$ is the plane that passes by the point $\begin{pmatrix}3\\0\\3\end{pmatrix}$, and having $\left(\vec u\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}, \vec v\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}\right)$ as a base.

Answer (score 1):

In your title you ask
"What does this notation mean" $$p_1 \ldots \frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y+1}{-1}=\frac{z-4}{1}, \quad p_2 \ldots \frac{x-5}{2}=\frac{y-1}{-1}=\frac{z-2}{1}$$

$p_1$ and $p_2$ are the name of the two lines. A line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be described as the intersections of two planes. A plane in $\mathbb R^3$ can be described by a linear equation in the coordinates $x,y,z$.

$$\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y+1}{-1}=\frac{z-4}{1}$$ is an abbreviation for

$$\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y+1}{-1}\\ \tag 1
\frac{y+1}{-1}=\frac{z-4}{1}$$
and therefore
$$\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y+1}{-1}$$
but one equation is redundant because it can be derived from the other two.

So $(1)$ is a system of two equations in $\mathbb R^3$ and their intersection is the line $p_1$.

How to find the plane is already described in a different post